# Java synchronize thread with buffer reading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, buffer

I am rendering the preview from the phone camera in android on a `GLSurfaceView` and want to save frames as soon as they are available. Since saving the frames to the sd card takes much more time than the time between two `onFrameAvailable` calls, I am doing it in another thread, after I read the pixels from the screen.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
//Process the frame, display it on the screen and other stuff

//Read pixels from the screen into my buffer
       glReadPixels(0, 0, offscreenSize_.x, offscreenSize_.y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                intBuffer.clear());
     // At the moment this has a counter and happens every 150ms
     if(saveImage)
     {
     Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Convert to an array for Bitmap.createBitmap().
                final int[] pixels = new int[intBuffer.capacity()];
                intBuffer.rewind();
                intBuffer.get(pixels);

                try {
                    // Create/access a pictures subdirectory.
                    File directory = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                            "TangoFrames");
                    if (!directory.mkdirs() && !directory.isDirectory()) {
                        Log.d("WRITE ERR", "Couldn't create directory");
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get the current capture index to construct a unique filename.
                    SharedPreferences prefs = activity_.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    int index = prefs.getInt("index", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putInt("index", index + 1);
                    prefsEditor.apply();

                    // Create the capture file.
                    File file = new File(directory, String.format("tango%05d.png", index));
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    // Bitmap conveniently provides file output.
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, offscreenSize_.x, offscreenSize_.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fileOutputStream);
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    numberOfFrames++;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the thread starts falling behind, it sometimes happens that for a frame for which the reading starts:

```
final int[] pixels = new int[intBuffer.capacity()];
intBuffer.rewind();
intBuffer.get(pixels);
```

The next callback is fired and `intBuffer.clear()` is run, so the rest gets corrupted.
How can I synchronize the thread in such a way that it would only run whenever the buffer is full and take care that the buffer doesn't get cleared while the thread is running?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're hitting a classic *shared data* concurrency problem.

The easiest way to solve such a problem is to stop sharing data. You can send to the worker thread a copy of the backing `int` array of the `IntBuffer`:

```
...
glReadPixels(0, 0, offscreenSize_.x, offscreenSize_.y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      intBuffer.clear());
final int[] bufferContents = intBuffer.array();
final int[] pixels = Arrays.copyOf(bufferContents , bufferContents .length);
// reset buffer here
if (saveImage) {
   ...
   // use pixels here
```

Simple synchronization of the reads and writes to the `IntBuffer` will "sequentialize" the critical sections of your program and may result in lower fidelity of the grabbed frames (you won't be able to call `glReadPixels` immediately when your frame change event listener is triggered, if your worker thread is still reading the `IntBuffer` contents). It will also be more error prone, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just using a `Queue` of `IntBuffer` objects, and waiting for the `Queue` to be empty before exiting the app. Basically running the function when `onPause` is called.

So for whoever reads this, it might be the case that you can just add your data to a queue and wait for it to be processed before exiting.